# Does locking an object reference lock the object or the reference?

Tags: c#, object, locking

Say I have an array of an object:

```
MyObject[] objects = new MyObject[10];
```

Then I loop through the array, and lock each object for processing by array index:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    lock (objects[i])
    {
        // process objects[i]
    }
}
```

does that mean the object itself is locked? Or the reference object[i] is locked? Will another call to the same object from elsewhere other than through this array be blocked?

Comment: You're not locking the object. You're locking the code between the curly braces. `{}`

Comment: @ Dennis  I'm confused. What's the difference between lock (specificObject) and lock (randomObject)? Is there basically no difference? Surely the object you are locking has something to do with it.

Comment: I think about the object as the 'key', or a 'baton' that gets passed around to threads when they want to access that piece of code.

Comment: @Dennis_E: Don't forget that two pieces of code can be under the same lock, and one piece of code can be under multiple locks.  Better I think to conceptualize the lock as entering a monitor; the code just follows the enter.

Comment: If you are interested in the fundamentals of locking my article on how an extremely simple locking system can be built out of smaller parts might be of interest to you. http://blog.coverity.com/2014/02/12/how-does-locking-work/#.Vxoj9o-cHic

Comment: @EricLippert I will go read that, thanks. I always enjoy reading your articles. I know locking is more complicated than I make it sound, but it helps me to think about it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock mechanism is associated with the object, not with the reference, and not with the variable.

So yes, locking on the same object instance somewhere else and on another thread will block that somewhere else until you exit the lock in your example code.

Please note that code on other threads that do not use `lock` or `Monitor.Enter` will *not* be blocked.

Also, note that exceptions inside the statement block of the lock will exit that block and release the lock, possibly leaving whatever you locked in a corrupted state.